# Partially apply mplus to rewrite function in point-free style

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm going through some Haskell tutorials and trying to get familiar with the language. I've seen this example in a Monad/MonadPlus tutorial:

```
data Sheep = Sheep {name :: String, mother :: Maybe Sheep, father :: Maybe Sheep}
parent :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
parent s = mother s `mplus` father s
```

I was trying to rewrite it in point-free style (just as an exercise, not saying that the above is wrong or non-idiomatic), but I got stuck: obviously I can write a custom function

```
partialPlus :: (MonadPlus m) => (a -> m b) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m b
partialPlus f1 f2 = \x -> f1 x `mplus` f2 x
```

and then use

```
parent = partialPlus mother father
```

but I seem to remember from the LYAH tutorial that there was a way to use functors or applicative functors to construct tree of computations that can be finally fed arguments to get the result out of the "functor-box". However I can't seem to find the example in the tutorial. How do I rewrite the above "cleverly"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Applicative instance for functions:

```
parent :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
parent = mplus <$> mother <*> father
```

Comment: what the hell, i swear this is what came to my mind and tried first :D not sure why it didn't work. thanks!

Comment: bonus: how to write `grandparent :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep` in point-free style? It should be something like `mplus <$> (parent ??? mother) <*> (parent ??? father)`, where `???` is again applicative or monadic, so that you propagate Nothing correctly. It seems that I always get stuck when I want to be clever...

Comment: @BruceBerry: You can use the `>=>` (aka. Kleisli composition) operator, which is like `flip (.)` with monads, so `grandparent = parent >=> parent`.

Comment: thanks. it seems that most monad tutorials do not introduce this operator, though i've seen it a bunch of times already. again, i'm probably trying to be too clever for my own good, and `grandparent s = (father s >>= parent) \`mplus\` (mother s >>= parent)` is perfectly fine, but it seems that haskell library writers do not really embrace simplicity, so I have some work do to before I can understand their code :-)

Answer (score 4):

### Very point-free

You could write it as

```
partialPlus :: MonadPlus m => (t -> m a) -> (t -> m a) -> t -> m a
partialPlus = liftM2 mplus
```

this works because of the monad instance for `(->) t` (which you can think of as meaning `(t ->)`.

The types in more detail:

```
liftM2 :: Monad func_t => (a -> b -> c) -> func_t a -> func_t b -> func_t c
```

Giving it the highly prejudicial name `func_t` to suggest function from t to...

so then

```
liftM2 mplus :: (Monad func_t, MonadPlus m) => func_t (m a) -> func_t (m a) -> func_t (m a)
```

### But why use Monad when you can have the nicer Applicative?

Or Why I stole hammar's nice answer:

Now, there's an applicative instance for `(->) t` and so we could just as well have written

```
partialPlus = liftA2 mplus
```

which works for exactly the same reason. But that's great news, because if you can use `liftA2` or `liftA3` etc, you can do it with the awesome `<$>` and `<*>` from `Control.Applicative`.

In general, if you have

```
this = do
  x <- mx
  y <- my
  z <- mz
  return (f x y z)
```

that's expressible as `liftM3 f mx my mz`, but more nicely as `f <$> mx <*> my <*> mz`, especially if `mx` and `my` etc are actually more complicated expression, as I find usually. `<*>` and `<*>` have low precedence (4) so you don't need brackets most of the time.

In this case we can have

```
partialPlus f1 f2 = mplus <$> f1 <*> f2
```

which is point-free. (...as long as you consider `t -> m a` as not a point!)